# Much lower temps on Ubuntu

Tags: cpu, gpu, temperature

I've noticed that CPU temps and GPU on my laptop are much lower on Ubuntu than Windows 7. On Windows temperature is like 50 celsius to 58 and on Ubuntu 40 to 50 max. Cooling is also much cooler on Ubuntu. I'm wondering what is causing that difference. Can you help me find an answer? Thanks for reply.

Comment: The fan is normally permanently on, especially if you haven't installed any extra drivers. Is the fact that it is cooler better or not good?

Comment: Not really. Fan speed is also lower on Ubuntu. On Windows when CPU hits 55 celsius the fan is going faster and louder. Now I have 39-42 on Ubuntu it's almost 20 degree difference than Windows.

Comment: @user3248114 please be as accurate as possible. Fanspeed is important info ;) So is battery life. And also what you -do- with Windows. Example: If you run an apache server on W and not on U that makes a diff. ;)

Comment: I'm doing the same thing ofc. Browsing an internet with Mozilla Firefox with 5 tabs opened and listen music from YT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm wondering what is causing that difference.

It mostly depends on what software you run on Windows and on Ubuntu.

In general Ubuntu has less software active and Windows tends to pre-load a lot of software during booting to speed things up when the desktop is active. Both might add to lower/higher temps.

> Can you help me find an answer?

Sure but you will need to do all the work. Download for both Ubuntu and Windows software that can check the load of your system. For Ubuntu you already have top and htop but powertop is a good tool for this.

Also take note of your fan: if Windows turns it off on occasion and Ubuntu has it at full speed all the time this will make a difference. And you should also look at the battery when discharging. If your battery life on Windows is better than on Ubuntu you might trade the "Ubuntu is cooler than Windows" for a "Ubuntu lasts not as long on battery as Windows" where the battery life is drained due to overactive fans.

(40-50 is nice. Very nice even. But a temp of 58 is not bad either).